# Can I use Firebase ML Kit Real-Time face detection in background as service?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-service, firebase-mlkit

I am making a kids learning app that will detect facial expressions of a kid in real-time and when the kid will get bored it will automatically change the learning process to some kind of poem or song. I am doing it using the firebase ML Kit. I have the code that is detecting faces in real-time but I want it to detect that in the background. 
Is there any way I can do it?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!